# javascript - simple way to display SQL single column value for input value

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, cordova

I'm a new Cordova-Android program maker. I've successfully create and insert the local database fields. But I stuck when I want to display them into `input` tag.

This is my table :

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | word | stats   |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | abc  | stackov |
| 2  | def  | erflow  |
+----+------+---------+
```

I try this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        docDB = window.openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "Test Data", 50000);

        docDB.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE word='abc'", [], function (tx, results) {
                var dblen = results.rows.length;
                if( dblen>0 ){
                    document.getElementById("abc").value = results.rows.item(0)['stats'];
                    }
            }, null);
        });
   });
```

I've searching for simplest way, because I just want to display single SQL column value `word='abc'` and other `word` value such `word='def'`. Can someone correct it?

And I would insert the result value into a `input` field

```
Name : <input type="text" id="abc">
```

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Are you listening to the deviceready event? And are there some datas in the database?

Comment: yes I did declare deviceready. and yes, the database and the data is exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your search value outside of the SQL statement and refer to the `item` as an object, see below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    docDB = window.openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "Test Data", 50000);

    docDB.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE word=?", ['abc'], function (tx, results) {
            var dblen = results.rows.length;
            if( dblen>0 ){
                document.getElementById("abc").value = results.rows.item(0).stats;
                }
        }, null);
    });
});
```

Removing the search parameters from the actual SQL statement has a few different benefits. One is, by passing in the variables they are escaped correctly as to not break the statement. Another is, it makes the statement more clear when debugging code.

For those who may not be familiar with the syntax, you add `?` where you would place variable input or a search parameter and then in the array after the statement `[]` items are removed from the array and added to the SQL statement.

Example:

```
..."SELECT * FROM thisTable WHERE id IN(?) AND name LIKE ? and gender=?", ['1,32,456', '%tim%', 'M']
```

Generates:

```
"SELECT * FROM thisTable WHERE id IN('1,32,456') AND name LIKE '%tim%' and gender='M'"
```

Comment: Hi Dawson, thankyou very much. I don't understand about this `[ ]` mean before

Answer (score 0):

You need to reaffirm the assessment in your sql code